# copying local folder to hdfs through R

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rhadoop

I am trying to export a folder from my local file system to hdfs . I am running code through R . How may I be able to do it?

Hope for suggestions

Comment: just use hadoop fs -put localpath hdfspath r not required

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `system` command to do that easily:

```
system("hadoop fs -put /path/to/file /path/in/hdfs")
```

You can also use the [rhdfs](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs) project, particularly the functions `hdfs.write` or `hdfs.copy` which should do the same.